# RDS SQL Server Execute permission denied on object in msdb database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have a RDS SQL Server instance where in I logged in as a master user. When I try to create a category for my jobs the execution of the  SP, sp_add_category fails with permission denied error.

Can anyone please guide me if this permission is available for us to change? Obviously, grant exec on the SP didn't work.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_add_category
    @class=N'JOB',
    @type=N'LOCAL',
    @name=N'AdminJobs' ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mention the SQL server version and edition you running on AWS. Not all editions in RDS support SQL agent jobs. 

Also please post the code you used.

Comment: @Ranch It's SQL 2016 Enterprise edition